# How to erase draw in graphics screen

Tags: qt4

I am writing an application in QT which will display maps in a widget.And It wil also draw a route from start to end point given co-ordinates.Now the problem is if i just want to undo the drawing the route( i mean to erase).The follwing code snippets will ll how i am drawing.

```
    QGeoMapRouteObject *route = new QGeoMapRouteObject(reply->routes().at(0));
    QColor routeColor(Qt::blue);
    routeColor.setAlpha(127);
    QPen pen(routeColor);
    pen.setWidth(3);
    pen.setCapStyle(Qt::MPenCapStyle);
    route->setPen(pen);
```

Here this class "QGeoMapRouteObject " doesnt have other options except setPen.Please let me know how can i draw and erase the route using this class "QGeoMapRouteObject".

Answer (score 0):

QGeoMapRouteObject cannot undo the process. Because it is the object being called. Only calling Object(in your case Graphics view) can undo the effect.`Just like Pixmap being an object and painter the parent object, Pixmap itself can't draw a Line in it.`

Comment: thanks for the response spyke.Even I am thinking the same.Thanks for the suggestion :-)